# Foundation Top Nav: dropdown menu parent link not working

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, nav

I recently started working with Foundation and I had been using Zurb's top nav solution successfully until yesterday when the parent links of dropdown menus decided to no longer operate as links in FF/Chrome. They still work in IE/Opera (haven't tested Safari). Removing the "has-dropdown" class allows them to work across all browsers again.

- Did a quick search through everything I've modified since they stopped working and I don't see any changes that I've made that could affect the default behavior of the onClick function for dropdown parent links.
- They still show up as links onHover
- They don't produce an error message in Chrome Developer Console/FF Firebug
- Live site is visible here: https://actitracker.com

Comment: - Made a jsFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/JX4Sk/1/ ) to see if any of my other code is conflicting and the issue still persists NOTE: Adjust width of rendered section to see full menu, not responsive version

Comment: I just tested on a few other machines as a sanity check and replicated the issue in FF/Chrome. For example, clicking "About" does not take you to the corresponding link, and neither does "Login".

Comment: Downgrading Foundation's JS files from 4.3.x to 4.2.x got everything working again. I noticed that the fiddle is using foundation.min.js version 4.1.x so it's not the same environment as the website (which is now running 4.2.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, Chrome was registering as both a touchscreen AND a large screen (i.e. not in mobile view which is medium/small/tiny). Because Modernizr saw that touch was present, Foundation used a mobile-friendly stylesheet which disabled things like clickable parent menus for the topbar.

Now, I don't actually have a touchscreen. However, I had been using a Leap Motion device and even when it was unplugged, Chrome did not revert back to non-touch settings. By going into chrome://flags/ and switching off the touch optimizations, I was able to get the user agent settings to refresh. Alternatively, uninstalling the Leap Motion Touchless for Windows app also does the trick.

Edit: Another option is also disabling touch-based input in Pen & Tablet Settings when Leap Motion is not in use.

Comment: This, pointed me in the right direction. In my case, I had manually enabled touch events on Firefox for testing months ago and forgot all about it. Thanks.